# How to prove that the following language is not decidable?

Tags: turing-machines, decidable

```
L = { <M> | M is a Turing machine over {0, 1}, and <M>||<M> (not in) L(M)}
```

How do I prove that L is not recognizable? Any ideas?

I've proven the `L compliment` is recognizable:

```
Set Turing machine to J 
1. Run J on input <M>||<M>
2. TM J accepts then accept, it reject the reject.

<M>||<M> is the concatenation of the encoding of the Turing machine.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the (diagonal) acceptance problem to this problem. I try to use your own notation

```
D = { <M> | M is a Turing machine over {0, 1}, and <M> (not in) L(M)}
```

Suppose to fix an encoding of machine M, and consider a new program that takes in input a string w and accepts it just in case `<M> in L(M)` (so it has a constant behaviour, independent from the input string, and only dependent on `<M>`).
The previous program can be build parametrically and effectively in `<M>`, that is we have a total computable function h such that the previous program has code
`h(<M>)`. Formally, I am using the smn theorem here, but since I am not sure you are confident with it, I prefer not mentioning it.

Now the question is if `h(<M>) is in L`.

If `<M> in D`, then by construction the machine `h(<M>)` does not accept any string, and in particular does not accept `h(<M>)||h(<M>)`, so `h(<M>)` in L.

Conversely, if `<M> not in D`, then by construction the machine `h(<M>)` does accept any string, and in particular it accepts `h(<M>)||h(<M>)`, so `h(<M>)` not in L.

If we had a way to decide L, we would have a way to decide D, and we know that D is not decidable (in fact, it is productive, similarly to L).